# Azure CosmosDB connect with gremlin console to the emulator

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

i want to connect to the cosmosDB emulator with the gremlin console.

How should the yaml file look like.
Currently i tried:

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: 
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { 
serializeResultToString: true }}
```

Here the command line call with response:
[image]

Here is the error message without ":>"
[image]

But this doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Kind Regards
Markus

Comment: Can you please share more details on the kind of error/behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Added a screenshot from the command call and the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use `gremlin console` to connect my `Azure Cosmos DB`, which worked well.

My configuration looks like:

```
hosts: [jaygong.graphs.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/testdb/colls/jay
password: ****************
connectionPool: {enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

[image]

Then, I followed your configuration and tried to connect `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`.

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8081
username: /dbs/familyDB/colls/FamilyCollection
password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

After a lot of trying, I also met the issue which is same as you.

[image]

Finally, I found this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599065-azure-cosmos-db-graph-api/suggestions/19636633-support-gremlin-apis-on-cosmos-db-emulator) and it seems that the `Cosmos DB Emulator` currently does not support the Gremlin API.

Considering for the cost, I suggest you use `Apache tinkerpop server` instead of `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` to test your code locally during the development stage. After the test is finished, turn to Azure Cosmos DB.

In addition, `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` supports `Graph API` which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction).

> By using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, you can use the Graph API to
>   develop and test locally without creating an Azure subscription or
>   incurring any costs. When you're satisfied with how your application
>   is working in the Emulator, you can switch to using an Azure Cosmos DB
>   account in the cloud.

This passage can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction).However,after my research for the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graph&type=), the Emulator supported Graph API mentioned here only refers to `.Net`,
not refers to [java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java) or [node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java).

So,it seems that the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator is deficient because it might not be up to date with the most recent changes with the Azure Cosmos DB service.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not work then i get this error message "No such property: g for class groovysh_evaluate"

Comment: @MarkusBenz Hi,please see my new answer.Thx.

Comment: If you do use the Apache tinkerpop server for development, make sure to a) check that the queries you are using only use the subset of gremlin which CosmosDB supports, and b) leave time for testing and optimizing on a full Azure CosmosDB Graph.

Answer (score 2):

Update, the emulator now supports gremlin, as of version `2.1.4.0` ([related GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16396)).

One of the users from that thread has even created a [repo with instructions for enabling it](https://github.com/MichalWierzbinski/cosmosdb-emulator-gremlin), via the `/EnableGremlinEndpoint` switch.